# How to get model instances instead of associative arrays from custom repository's select query

Tags: php, typo3

I have this repository, which works per se:

```php
<?php

namespace Homeinfo\SysMon2\Domain\Repository;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Connection;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryResultInterface;

final class CheckResultsRepository
{    
    public function __construct(
        private readonly ConnectionPool $connectionPool
    ) {
    }

    public function findBySystem(int $system) {
        $queryBuilder = $this->connectionPool->getQueryBuilderForTable('checkresults');
        $result = $queryBuilder
            ->select('*')
            ->from('checkresults')
            ->where(
                $queryBuilder->expr()->eq(
                    'system',
                    $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter($system, Connection::PARAM_INT)
                )
            )
            ->executeQuery();
        return $result->fetchAll();
    }
}
```

However, the data returned by `fetchAll()` is an array of associative arrays representing the table columns.
I have this model:

```php
<?php

namespace Homeinfo\SysMon2\Domain\Model;

use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity;

class CheckResults extends AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * @var int $id
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @var DateTime $timestamp
     */
    public $timestamp;

    /**
     * @var int $system
     */
    public $system;

    /**
     * @var bool $icmp_request 
     */
    public $icmp_request;

    /**
     * @var string $ssh_login  
     */
    public $ssh_login ;

    /**
     * @var string $http_request 
     */
    public $http_request;

    /**
     * @var string $application_state 
     */
    public $application_state;

    /**
     * @var string $smart_check 
     */
    public $smart_check;

    /**
     * @var string $baytrail_freeze 
     */
    public $baytrail_freeze;

    /**
     * @var string $fsck_repair 
     */
    public $fsck_repair;

    /**
     * @var bool $application_version 
     */
    public $application_version;

    /**
     * @var int $ram_total 
     */
    public $ram_total;

    /**
     * @var int $ram_free 
     */
    public $ram_free;

    /**
     * @var int $ram_available 
     */
    public $ram_available;

    /**
     * @var string $efi_mount_ok 
     */
    public $efi_mount_ok;

    /**
     * @var int $download 
     */
    public $download;

    /**
     * @var int $upload 
     */
    public $upload;

    /**
     * @var string $root_not_ro 
     */
    public $root_not_ro;

    /**
     * @var string $sensors 
     */
    public $sensors;

    /**
     * @var bool $in_sync 
     */
    public $in_sync;

    /**
     * @var int $recent_touch_events 
     */
    public $recent_touch_events;

    /**
     * @var DateTime $offline_since 
     */
    public $offline_since;

    /**
     * @var DateTime $blackscreen_since 
     */
    public $blackscreen_since;
}
```

What is the correct way to make the above function yield instances of that model instead of associative arrays?

Comment: You have to build it on your own. Under the hood Doctrine DBAL is used, which returns an array.
Alternatively, use an Extbase repository (which provides an ORM) instead of using the query builder: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/Extbase/Reference/Domain/Repository.html

Comment: I think that using extbase is not possible in my case, since it's a foreign database not containing `uid` or `pid` fields.

Comment: You could map your `id` as `uid`, and the `pid` is IMO not required if you set `$querySettings->setRespectStoragePage(false);`... Should be worth a try.